# qt creator: subclassing a custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, custom-widgets

I want to derive a child class from an already customized widget in qt creator:

MyCustomWidget.h:

```
class MyCustomWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
```

MyChildCustomWidget.h:

```
class MyChildCustomWidget : public MyCustomWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
```

Ok this is easy.

But how do I tell qt creator/designer to use MyChildCustomWidget?? It only allows me to use MyCustomWidget in the list of custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt Designer right click on the widget and then:

[image]

Read also [Using Custom Widgets with Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) and [Creating Custom Widgets for Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) (thanks maxik for adding these links)

Comment: Some reference here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/designer-using-custom-widgets.html for placeholder widgets. More in depth integration documented here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html.

Comment: @maxik Thank you, I added these links to the answer